# Workflow languages?

Tags: workflow, workflow-definition-language

I am looking for a list of current workflow languages. I know about [BPEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language), [WS-CDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-CDL) and [YAWL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAWL). What other current languages are there? A short description of how they operate would be excellent. All suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are interesting in high performace and easy develompent of workflow processes just follow this link:
http://www.gp-solutions.si/business/Product.aspx?s=stack&id=1&cat=2

GPWF allows you much more than you required in this question.

Comment: @GregorPrimar your link is dead!

Comment: Yes, new website is now dedicated only to this product. The biggest customer is running more than 13k of process instances and related documents over this system per day. Here is new link:
http://www.gpwf.si

Answer (score 5):

You could have a long at workflow definition languages from the point of view of workflow patterns :

http://workflowpatterns.com/evaluations/

How "standards" fare may interest you :

http://workflowpatterns.com/evaluations/standard/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Try WWF(Windows Workflow Foundation, Part of .NET Framework) 
you can read about it here-
http://www.windowsworkflowfoundation.eu/

Answer (score 2):

For BizTalk there is also [XLANG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577463(BTS.70).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Cameleon**: http://www.shinoe.org/cameleon which seems to be simple to use.
Its written in C++ but can call any type of local or distant programs writen in any programming language.

It has a multi-scale approach and seems to be turing complete (this is a petri net extension).

sheers,