# Mapping of YAWL onto BPMN and vice versa

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, yawl

Can somebody please guide me whether there is an overview (diagram?) showing which language elements map onto each other (or a construct in the other language) and which are unique in either BPMN or [YAWL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAWL)?

Can somebody please tell me which YAWL elements are not mapped onto BPMN elements and vice versa?

**References:** Aside from the two respective defining foundations, all I find is in-depth info is a research paper on [Transformation of BPMN to YAWL](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221196313_Transformation_of_BPMN_to_YAWL) (which is one-way).

- [Migrating YAWL files (*.ywl) to BPMN 2.0 schema files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035728/migrating-yawl-files-ywl-to-bpmn-2-0-schema-files)
- [Daniela Cristina Cascini Peixoto et. al.: *A Comparison of BPMN and UML 2.0 Activity Diagrams*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228965384_A_Comparison_of_BPMN_and_UML_20_Activity_Diagrams)
- [Workflow languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627754/workflow-languages)
- [Map bpmn to wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326677/map-bpmn-to-wsdl)
- [Which of these technology to use for BPM / Workflow engine? Any comparison of features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029608/which-of-these-technology-to-use-for-bpm-workflow-engine-any-comparison-of-fe/21045665#21045665)
- [Map bpmn to wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326677/map-bpmn-to-wsdl)

**Disclaimer:** I am fluent in BPM (in particular BPMN), as well as graph theory in general, but I am new to YAWL.

Comment: Most publications I found present algorithms for migrating BPMN models to YAWL: http://www.jsoftware.us/vol5/jsw0504-6.pdf and https://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/pub/Public/GeroDecker/bpmdemo2008-bpmn2yawl.pdf. Apparently there is a paper for bi-directional mapping, but I could not download it: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289023783_Bidirectional_mapping_between_YAWL_and_BPMN

Comment: @M.F. Why don't you just write an answer so that I can reward the bounty to you, please? I already prepared a draft you can copy from.

Comment: http://www.yaug.org/node/600

Comment: @B--rian sorry, I was out for a while and I've only seen your message now. I guess it's too late for the bounty, but no worries, I'm happy if the links I sent are pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a YAWL XML format definition which can be compared with the BPMN XML format definition.

> [The YAWL Usergroup] would also like to point you to Apromore and [a related discussion in the YAWL User Group Forum](http://www.yaug.org/node/600):
>
> 1. There is an [XSD file that specifies the YAWL XML format](https://github.com/yawlfoundation/yawl/blob/master/schema/YAWL_Schema4.0.xsd)
> 2. There is a tool called [apromore](https://apromore.org/) which converts BPMN or other formats into the YAWL XML format.

Comment: @yawl-usergroup For a discussion about the (incorrectly as spam marked) official answer, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393672/how-can-i-get-back-a-deleted-answer-that-i-found-helpful/393684#393684

Answer (score 0):

[M.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7316656/m-f) found the a manuscript by
**J.-H. Ye & S. Ye:** *Bidirectional mapping between YAWL and BPMN*. We both do not have access to the manuscript (yet), but the abstract looks promising.

> The modeling language mapping between BPMN and YAWL was researched. The transformation benefited the choice of different modeling languages and reduced duplication of development costs. As a proof of concept, the algorithm was implemented, and two open-sources plug-in called BPMN2YAWL and YAWL2BPMN are available in ProM6.0.
>
> Source: [Researchgate.net: *Bidirectional mapping between YAWL and BPMN*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289023783_Bidirectional_mapping_between_YAWL_and_BPMN)